# Passing file download via php very slow

Tags: php, apache2

I have a window 2003 dedicated server, i have installed xampp on it.

So i tried to pass download using PHP script such as zina from pancake.org, phpIndexer php functions such as fread, fgets, file, file_get_contents;

If i download let say from apache mod_dirlisting, the speed is 1mbps however on same server with using php, the speed dropped to 30kbps.

Any idea what causing it? should i tweak any php.ini to reflect?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "download from mod_dirlisting"? You mean a direct file download from apache (without PHP)?

Comment: @pekka, yes, direct from apache.

Comment: then you should show your PHP code.

Comment: i tried various PHP download script available on net to test, its all same, 30kbps and so.

Example, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php#84115

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `readfile` function ([see PHP doc](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)). `fread` or `file_get_contents` read file to memory then you send it by `print` or `echo`, `readfile` reads the file directly to the output buffer, should be faster.